# Laravel-5.5: Session store not set on request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have simple controller:

#### Code InboxController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class InboxController extends Controller
{
    public function compose(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {

            $rules = [
                'to'      => 'required|email',
                'from'    => 'required|email',
                'subject' => 'required|max:10',
                'message' => 'required'
            ];

            $this->validate($request, $rules);

        }

        $array = array('messages'=>$this->user_messages(), 'count' => $this->count_messages());

        return view('compose', $array);
    }
}
```

And if I want validate sended data in all routes give error:

```
Session store not set on request.
```

How I can set session on request in Laravel 5.5 for validate data?
I must validate data in `compose` route

```
Routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'inbox', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'InboxController@index',])->name('inbox');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/message/{id?}', ['uses'=>'InboxController@message'])->name('message');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/compose', ['uses'=>'InboxController@compose'])->name('compose');
});
```

My middleware group code:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

Comment: show us your kernel middlewareGroup

Comment: You can see middleware group in updated question @Sohel0415

Comment: change `return view('compose', compact('array'));` instead of `return view('compose', $array);`

Comment: if you don't assign the `web` group to your routes you don't have sessions

Answer (score 2):

You Need to add

```
 \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

in middle ware inside kernal.php web group.

Comment: I already have add this class but I not use middleware['web'] in my route. U use only middleware['auth']. And where is error? How to fix it? @Saurabh Parekh

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the web middleware if you need session state, CSRF protection, and more.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
// your routes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS HAPPENING BECAUSE**

in Kernal.php (location -> /app/Http )

there are two arrays **$middleware** and **$routeMiddleware**.

**Do not** create alias(naming) inside $middleware array. it has to be created in $routeMiddleware array.

for example

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'checkLogin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckLogin::class,
    //here you have to add your middleware naming not in the $middleware array
];
```